# Facebook Unity SDK login not taking me back to my app om some Android devices

Tags: facebook-unity-sdk

On a Sony Ericsson Experia with FB app installed (and me logged into it), the facebook login isn't working with the latest plugin (oct 13th build). I tap my connect button, it switches to the facebook activity, then redirects me to a browser, which redirects to another browser page pointing at "fbconnect://success#access_token=CAABZ....." which just says "Web Page not available". So it looks like it's working, just doesn't come back to my app.

Here is the output of logcat after I click login:

> E/ActivityThread(13575): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.AttributionIdProvider
>   D/PhoneWindow(13575): couldn't save which view has focus because the focused view com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$24@2b005760 has no id.
>   I/ActivityManager(  237): Starting: Intent { act=SSO_WITH_FALLBACK cmp=com.fluik.MyGame/com.facebook.LoginActivity (has extras) } from pid 13575
>   E/ActivityThread(13575): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.PlatformProvider
>   I/ActivityManager(  237): Starting: Intent { cmp=com.facebook.katana/.ProxyAuth (has extras) } from pid 13575
>   I/ActivityManager(  237): Displayed com.facebook.katana/.ProxyAuth: +328ms (total +587ms)
>   I/ActivityManager(  237): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=https://m.facebook.com/dialog/permissions.request?app_id=138830872932854&client_id=138830872932854&redirect_uri=fbconnect%3A%2F%2Fsuccess&type=user_agent&perms=email%2Cuser_birthday&fbconnect=1&sso=android&android_key=hhffGIAnpPWh4E4lLnO-jseVpiU&_path=permissions.request cmp=com.android.browser/.BrowserActivity } from pid 9026
>   I/ActivityManager(  237): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW cat=[android.intent.category.BROWSABLE] dat=https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=138830872932854&redirect_uri=fbconnect%3A%2F%2Fsuccess&type=user_agent&fbconnect=1&sso=android&android_key=hhffGIAnpPWh4E4lLnO-jseVpiU&scope=email%2Cuser_birthday&_rdr cmp=com.android.browser/.BrowserActivity } from pid 13494
>   E/Tab     (13494): onReceivedError -10 fbconnect://success#access_token=CAABZBRBTdcfYBALJgE64WnGcfAfORTZA0wHYwsKvL7lApIjrdIUqNzDEqHsVhnWQjCwU9KLsZBB7pWUiwsZAlhnc5jMQEUeHlZAVFobn8aqVpTEQJmFjxyiZAZCnVZCvdJfZB14sfO545tc0ZAYR7g81pChZA0phZAx1nh3deje1t4NsvU7nPj0PG0mscj88S8ZBdTGlGXkYl5dVRZCo2v6x8G4IpX&expires_in=5182746 The protocol is not supported.

One time it did come back to the app, and I got a new null pointer on login, being reported as from LoginActivity, ultimately looks to be coming from:

```
com.facebook.AuthorizationClient.logAuthorizationMethodComplete(
     AuthorizationClient.java:519)
```

Looking at the code, the only thing that could cause null pointer here seems to be the logger not being initialized:

```
this.appEventsLogger.logSdkEvent(
     "fb_mobile_login_method_start", null, bundle);
```

Here's the stack trace.

> E/AndroidRuntime(13363): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.fluik.WordMeisterFree/com.facebook.LoginActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure >delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=64206, result=0, data=null} to activity {com.fluik.WordMeisterFree/com.facebook.LoginActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   E/AndroidRuntime(13363):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2141)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(13363):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2156)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(13363):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1680)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(13363):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:121)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(13363):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:943)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(13363):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(13363):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(13363):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(13363):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(13363):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(13363):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(13363):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:624)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(13363):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(13363): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=64206, result=0, data=null} to activity {com.fluik.WordMeisterFree/com.facebook.LoginActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   E/AndroidRuntime(13363):   at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2553)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(13363):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2128)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(13363):   ... 12 more
>   E/AndroidRuntime(13363): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   E/AndroidRuntime(13363):   at **com.facebook.AuthorizationClient.logAuthorizationMethodComplete(AuthorizationClient.java:519)**
>   E/AndroidRuntime(13363):   at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient.logAuthorizationMethodComplete(AuthorizationClient.java:487)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(13363):   at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient.complete(AuthorizationClient.java:297)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(13363):   at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient.completeAndValidate(AuthorizationClient.java:289)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(13363):   at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient$KatanaProxyAuthHandler.onActivityResult(AuthorizationClient.java:948)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(13363):   at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient.onActivityResult(AuthorizationClient.java:187)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(13363):   at com.facebook.LoginActivity.onActivityResult(LoginActivity.java:138)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(13363):   at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3908)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(13363):   at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2549)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(13363):   ... 13 more

Any help would be appreciated...

**UPDATE:**
Just wanted to mention that I built the demo project, i.e. Interactive Console scene in a clean project, and got the exact same behaviour...

**UPDATE 2:**
I tried it again on a different device (first was a Sony Ericsson Experia, second was Nexus 10), and it worked fine. Lovely. Welcome to android hell...

Anyhow, in case it can help identify the issue, here is the logcat output on the functioning nexus 10 after tapping Login:

> E/ActivityThread( 2755): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.AttributionIdProvider
>   I/ActivityManager(  463): START u0 {act=SSO_WITH_FALLBACK cmp=com.fluik.MyGame/com.facebook.LoginActivity (has extras)} from pid 2755
>   E/ActivityThread( 2755): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.PlatformProvider
>   D/FacebookSDK.WebDialog( 2755): Webview loading URL: https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?display=touch&e2e=%7B%22init%22%3A1382373838875%7D&client_id=138830872932854&scope=email%2Cuser_birthday&type=user_agent&redirect_uri=fbconnect%3A%2F%2Fsuccess
>   I/ActivityManager(  463): Displayed com.fluik.MyGame/com.facebook.LoginActivity: +363ms
>   D/FacebookSDK.WebDialog( 2755): Redirect URL: https://m.facebook.com/login.php?skip_api_login=1&api_key=138830872932854&signed_next=1&next=https%3A%2F%2Fm.facebook.com%2Fdialog%2Foauth%3Fredirect_uri%3Dfbconnect%253A%252F%252Fsuccess%26display%3Dtouch%26scope%3Demail%252Cuser_birthday%26type%3Duser_agent%26client_id%3D138830872932854%26ret%3Dlogin&cancel_uri=fbconnect%3A%2F%2Fsuccess%3Ferror%3Daccess_denied%26error_code%3D200%26error_description%3DPermissions%2Berror%26error_reason%3Duser_denied%26e2e%3D%257B%2522init%2522%253A1382373838875%257D&display=touch&_rdr
>   D/FacebookSDK.WebDialog( 2755): Webview loading URL: https://m.facebook.com/login.php?skip_api_login=1&api_key=138830872932854&signed_next=1&next=https%3A%2F%2Fm.facebook.com%2Fdialog%2Foauth%3Fredirect_uri%3Dfbconnect%253A%252F%252Fsuccess%26display%3Dtouch%26scope%3Demail%252Cuser_birthday%26type%3Duser_agent%26client_id%3D138830872932854%26ret%3Dlogin&cancel_uri=fbconnect%3A%2F%2Fsuccess%3Ferror%3Daccess_denied%26error_code%3D200%26error_description%3DPermissions%2Berror%26error_reason%3Duser_denied%26e2e%3D%257B%2522init%2522%253A1382373838875%257D&display=touch&_rdr

Comment: Thanks for the detailed information, Klaus. We'll see if we can repro this on the same hardware.

Answer (score -2):

Klaus Rubba,

Try unchecking "Don't keep activities" in your phones dev debug settings.  Also, when you call the FB login function only call for the "publish_action"  there is some kind of bug where you can not ask for read and write permissions at the same time for android.

Comment: This debug setting is created to emulate Android's behavor that can happen under different circumstances. So, by unchecking it, you solve the issue for yourself, but you're not solving the issue for users that experience this behaviour. This is a **bad** advice regardless the issue: it only hides the issue from the developer, but doesn't solve it for the users.